# Iterating through multiple fields on form post data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, I currently am able to get form post data from a two form fields of `name="start"` and `name="end"`. The post data is as follows:

```
start: 2018-05-18 12:00
end: 2018-05-18 12:00
```

Here is the code that takes the post data and does something with it.

```
post "/time" do
  time = DoTime.new
  start = params["start"]
  finish = params["end"]
  time.started_at = start
  time.finished_at = finish
  time.profile = current_user
  time.save
  redirect "/profile"
end
```

I have since implemented a dynamic form which allows the user to duplicate the start and end fields as many times as they want. All this does is add the HTML form fields in place before submission and posts it with the form. An example of the new post data is here:

```
start: 2018-05-18 12:00
end: 2018-05-18 12:00
start: 2018-05-19 12:00
end: 2018-05-19 12:00
```

I am wondering how I can loop through the ruby to look for each instance of `start` and `end` and run the code above for each of the elements it finds. Any pointers or advice? I have tried a few different ways but keep running into errors.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full value of `params`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you expect `params[:start]` and `params[:end]` to contain an array of dates. To be able to do that, you need to set the `name` attribute of all duplicate *start* fields to "start[]" and similarly for *end* fields, set it to "end[]".

Now, you can iterate on the values in your controller and create multiple objects as follows:

```
post "/time" do
  # Assuming the number of starts and ends will be same, ...
  params[:start].count.times do |i|
    time = DoTime.new
    time.started_at = params[:start][i]
    time.finished_at = params[:end][i]
    time.profile = current_user
    time.save!
  end

  redirect "/profile"
end
```

Comment: Hmmm. This is the solution I had @jagdeep but it doesn't seem to be coming through. I read online I might need to change the helper but can't understand. It seems to just get the last item in the form.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the redirect outside the loop and made the stupid mistake of leaving it in... All working perfecty, thank you!